# Unable to load some packages; R looking for gcc in old directory

Tags: r, gcc, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm having an issue will installing/ loading some packages in R. When I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
> library(asreml)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘asreml’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'asreml', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/asreml/libs/asreml.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/asreml/libs/asreml.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc@11/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/asreml/libs/asreml.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc@11/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

The last time I had this issue, I uninstalled and reinstalled the package, and that solved the problem. This time, however, that isn't working. I believe the issue is that it's looking for gcc in

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc@11/
```

but 12 is my most current version. HOWEVER, both

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc@11/
```

and

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc@12/
```

link to

```
../Cellar/gcc/12.2.0
```

So I'm not even sure if redirecting it would solve the issue. Any ideas? Thanks!